# How to upgrade Ocaml to the latest version to support QuickChick in Coq?

Tags: ocaml, upgrade, coq, ubuntu-18.04, opam

When I [installed `QuickChick` from `opam`](https://github.com/QuickChick/QuickChick#from-opam), I obtained:

> The following dependencies couldn't be met:
>
> - coq-quickchick → ocaml >= 4.04.0
>
>   base of this switch (use `--unlock-base` to force)

How should I upgrade `ocaml` to the latest version to support `QuickChick` ***without ruining the configuration of `Coq`***?

---

`which ocaml`:

> /home/hengxin/opam-coq.8.9.0/ocaml-base-compiler.4.02.3/bin/ocaml

`opam list`:
[image: opam-list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, using the suggested option (`--unlock-base`) will allow `opam` to upgrade your `ocaml` version and keep the same switch. However, since nearly all packages depend on the `ocaml` package, the operation will actually reinstall all the packages, so you won't gain much w.r.t. creating a new switch.

If you try this way, you may have to relock some packages afterwards (such as `ocaml`) to avoid modifying them in usual operations with `opam` (I do not remember whether that `--unlock-base` is temporary or permanent).

Comment: Thanks. I decided to create a new switch: `opam switch create 4.07.1`. Now, `opam list` and `which ocaml` show the new version: `/home/hengxin/opam-coq.8.9.0/4.07.1/bin/ocaml`. However, `which coqide` still shows `/home/hengxin/opam-coq.8.9.0/ocaml-base-compiler.4.02.3/bin/coqide`. How to configure Coq to use the latest `ocaml`?

Comment: You need to install `coq` and `coqide` in your new switch and make sure the environment is synchronised (typically with `eval $(opam env)`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm much afraid @hengxin that you may need to create a new switch; on the other hand that should ruin nothing, unless you have a very special setup.